# Laravel Socialite Providers - Microsoft Issue

Tags: laravel, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect, laravel-socialite

When implementing Laravel Socialite Providers for Microsoft to authenticate users below issue throws. How to fix this.

*GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested a (truncated...)*

[Azure Active Directory Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M8A4.png)

Comment: Maybe due to GuzzleHttp version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64498680/php-fatal-error-uncaught-guzzlehttp-exception-clientexception

Comment: I don't think laravel socialite supports Microsoft https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite#introduction

Comment: @omaresmaeel It does, there's a Socialite provider for [Microsoft](https://socialiteproviders.com/Microsoft/)

Comment: @nagidi other providers are working properly. Microsoft one is the only not working. brombeer Yes, that's the one I'm using

Comment: Edit your question and show the Azure Active Directory configuration for **API permissions** and **Expose an API**.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have added the permissions currently available.

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Also show your request with scopes.